# echo statement with php array

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am only just getting into PHP coding. I know what I may have isn't considered best practice but my question is

how can I create the select portion of the form in an echo statement.

I am trying to select rows from a database with mysqli_fetch_array.

I want to go through each row of my database and create the select portion of the form so that each selection will have a value corresponding to the vendor_id and I want the selection to print out the names of the vendor for the user to select.

At the end, I want to have something like the picture I posted, without having to hardcode the vendor information.

```
<HTML>
<?php 

# keep the sensitive information in a separated PHP file.
include 'dbinfo.php';

$con=mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$dbname)
     or die("<br>Cannot connect to DB\n");

session_start();
$row = $_SESSION['row'];

$query = " SELECT * FROM VENDOR group by vendor_id";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);



echo "<a href=\"CPS5920_employee_login.php\">Employee logout</a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<font size=4><b>Add products</b></font>";
echo "<br>";


echo "<form name='input' action='CPS5920_product_insert.php' method='post' >
<br> Product Name: <input type='text' name='product_name' required='required'>
<br> description: <input type='text' name='description' required='required'>
<br> Cost: <input type='text' name='cost' required='required'>
<br> Sell Price: <input type='text' name='sell_price' required='required'>
<br> Quantity: <input type='text' name='quantity' required='required'><br>";

while($venrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   echo " Select vendor: <SELECT>
   <option value = $venrow['vendor_id']> $venrow['name']</option>
   </SELECT>";
}

#ignore this echo. it is hardcoded at the moment
echo "<br><input type='hidden' name='employee_id' value= '2'>
<br><input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>";


mysqi_close($con);

?>
</HTML>
```

[image]

Comment: you want the form populated on the fly on change of the select box? you might need to use an xmlhttprequest for that.

Comment: when the page is created I want to be able to refer to the database, check my vendors, and make those vendors selectable options. If the database changes, I want the page to be dynamic in the sense that next time I open it, it will include new vendors as options.

Comment: You don't have to echo all the HTML. You can just write it plain and put any PHP in PHP tags i.e. <?php ... ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is simple. OP just wants to populate the `<select></select>` field with vendors coming from the database. And when a new vendor is added, and a user visited the form, the vendor field will be updated with newly added vendor/s.

---

Just wanted to point out:

- Put the `<select></select>` outside your while loop.
- Make sure also that you are connecting to your database properly.
- [Concat](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php) properly
- Do you receive any error when you run the code you have provided?
- Your table name is really all in upper case? `VENDOR`? Remember that MySQL is [case sensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html).

---

```
<select name="vendor">

    <?php

        $query = "SELECT * FROM VENDOR group by vendor_id";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        while($venrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<option value="'.$venrow['vendor_id'].'">'.$venrow['name'].'</option>';
        }

    ?>

</select>
```

Comment: very clear answer. Actually came up with the solution last night but forgot to edit. My issue was concat and the select tags. Currently connecting to a database that is not my own, so I do not have privileges to edit names and such. table names are all caps, yes. In any event, thanks!